# Laravel 4, Sentry 2: Permission levels possible?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, cartalyst-sentry

Sentry permissions look like this inside the database table:

```
{"admin":1,"create_news":1}
```

Is there a way to not only use boolean values but levels? Such as 0, 1, 2, 3, 4.

Sentry does not seem to support this by default. No idea why. The permission system is disappointing me, I cannot use it without permission levels.

Any ideas for a workaround? For testing I refactored some Sentry code so parts of permission levels do work now, but I don't want to change the vendor code. Can I extend classes such as Cartalyst\Users\Eloquent\User?

Comment: Just extend the Group handler from Sentry and modify it to support group permissions. Sentry itself doesn't support it, so you will have to modify it yourself.

Comment: Perhaps you should consider the underlying logic of your design.

why would you need different levels of a "create_news" permission?

Comment: I don't, I want to merge all permissions related to news to one: 0 = none, 1 = view_news, 2 = view_news AND create_news, 3 view_news, create_news AND update_news, 4 = view, create, update and delete_news. Already solved this by extending Sentry, but thank you.